# Sanyo battery: what 430MH stands for?

Tags: batteries, nimh, battery-chemistry

I have a SANYO NI-MH battery from my Oral-B toothbrush. I reads 430MH. Now I'm curious what does **430MH** stand for?

Im thinking its probably `nickel–metal hydride` if so, whats does the number (430) mean?

[image: SANYO 430MH]

Comment: It could be a logistical part number with little technical meaning.

Comment: I tried googling it. But no dice. Its a Sanyo battery. Let me make a picture and add it.

Comment: Ultimately, what are you aiming to achieve?

Comment: Well i like to know what it means (so i could find the correct replacement). Of course some googling suggest i can replace it with a 4/5A 2150 mAh, but is mainly curiosity.

Comment: Here's a [datsheet](http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Sanyo%20Energy/HR-45SCU.pdf) and [product page](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/HR-4%2F5SCUT/SY140T-ND/1203026) for a very similar type of battery (if not the excat same type) made by Sanyo.  It doesn't mention markings.  Your question, however, is a bit like [Douglas Adams' number 42](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#The_number_42).  We probably would not be able to guess what it stands for.

Comment: @NickAlexeev hehe, yeah good one. Thanks, i have seen a similar datasheet. Its weird since a google 'sanyo 430mh' brings nothing. Thought google would be able to solve, fail… ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is Sanyo's p/n or model #.  They usually stamp their rechargeables with a 3-to-4 digit code followed by "MH" (for NiMH), "LI" (for Lithium Ion) or no suffix (for NiCads).  It has nothing to do with capacity.

Answer (score 0):

The battery you're looking at isn't found unless you go to sanyo and tell them you're buying large quantities.

You could calculate the weight of the cylinder from the measurements and then
use the average energy density of NiMH batteries to figure out the capacity in the ballpark:
100 W·h/kg (Figure from wikipedia).

Use the average voltage of the battery to calculate amperes. This will be close, but it depends heavily upon the internal chemistry.

Answer (score -2):

It's likely that it stands for 430 milliAmp-Hours, a rating of battery capacity.

Comment: Thats what i thought at first. But this battery should be somewhere round the 1600-2150 mAh. So 430 would be way to low. Guess it means something else...

Comment: Agreed, then, if you know that the capacity is significantly higher, then it must stand for something else.  Maybe a date and factory code or something like that.